# Problem converting the string "0.5" to a number

Tags: vimscript, options

I'm currently reading [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/). I did the following experiments as an exercise in the book.

```
:let &wrap="1.5"
:let &wrap="0.5"
:let &wrap=str2nr("0.5",8)
```

The first one ran normally, but the second one complains `E521: Number required: &wrap = '0.5'`. I thought it was the leading zero that cause the error, perhaps it makes Vim regard it as a octal number. So I tested the third hoping it would produce the same error, but it executed normally. What's the reason of these scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is treating it as octal number. From `:help E521`:

```
Set string or number option to {value}.
For numeric options the value can be given in decimal,
hex (preceded with 0x) or octal (preceded with '0').
```

Trying without `.` - `let &wrap="05"` - Vim won't complain, so it has a problem with the `.` itself. If you try to run `:echo str2nr(".5",8)` it also won't fail and print `0`. Seems like a bug a bit, and lack of consistency.

Comment: Thanks! Though I think "0.5" and "05" are different things, in practice nobody would write as such. And only for Vimscript options would such inconsistency occur.

Comment: Yes, for us - people - they are different thigs, but Vim seems to treat both as octal number and fails on `.`